# ¿Qué significa "jalar" en México?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, méxico

¿Cuál es el significado de "jalar" para cada uno de estos ejemplos?

> 1. A pesar de que esta televisión la compré apenas el año pasado, ya no jala.
> 2. Ya no estés de ocioso, ¡ponte a jalar!
> 3. Persona A: ¿En dónde jalas? Persona B: En una empresa que se dedica a la manufactura de plasticos.
> 4. ¿Vas a ir a la fiesta? ¿jalas o te enclochas?

Revisé la RAE [jalar](http://dle.rae.es/jalar) y les puedo decir que ninguno de los significados para estos ejemplos viene ahí.

Comment: Va muy relacionado con la cultura del campo, donde un animal de carga o un vehículo puede o no jalar un arado, de donde deriva dependiendo del contexto, para cada frase que mencionas: funcionar, trabajar (relacionado a la idea de trabajar jalando un arado), ir (en este caso, similar a la idea de manejar un automotor a transmisión manual, donde enclochar se refiere a aplicar el embrague, deteniendo de esta forma el avance del vehículo).

Comment: @OmarSalinas ¡Interesante! Creo que tu comentario debería ser respuesta porque además de dar el significado estás mencionando una posible teoría del origen.

Comment: En España es muy coloquial, y sólo lo he escuchado con el sentido de comer, o más bien engullir con glotonería y sin masticar. Quizás tenga algo que ver con lo rápido que te tienes que comer unos jalapeños para sobrevivir al picor de boca, pero no es más que una teoría sin fundamento.

Comment: @Fran Ese uso que comentas si viene documentado en la RAE pero no es usado en México.

Comment: Otro uso muy común en México es relacionado con hacer pesas: "voy a jalar" = "voy a hacer pesas".

Comment: @SergioRomero es cierto ya lo había olvidado, por ejemplo "voy a jalar biceps" es "voy a ejercitar/trabajar el biceps".

Comment: En Chile "jalar" es aspirar cocaína.

Answer (score 10):

1. "Ya no jala" = "Ya no funciona"
2. "Ponte a jalar" = "Ponte a trabajar"
3. "En dónde jalas?" = "En dónde trabajas?"
4. "Jalas?" = "Vas?"

Answer (score 8):

En México va muy relacionado con la cultura del campo, donde un animal de carga o un vehículo puede o no jalar un arado, de donde deriva dependiendo del contexto, para cada frase que mencionas: funcionar, trabajar (relacionado a la idea de trabajar jalando un arado), ir (en este caso, similar a la idea de manejar un automotor a transmisión manual, donde enclochar se refiere a aplicar el embrague, deteniendo de esta forma el avance del vehículo).

Comment: Esta respuesta explica el origen de la expresión, sin limitarse a enumerar los casos de la pregunta original. Gracias a esto, podríamos descifrar el sentido de "*Me quede sin **jale** ayer, el jefe me corrió*" (*jale*, adverbio *ad-hoc* de **jalar** como **trabajar**, luego jale=trabajo) Otra expresión en el mismo sentido, sería ***En el trabajo de equipo, todos deben jalar parejo*** queriendo decir que la carga de trabajo debe ser distribuida equitativamente entre todos los miembros del equipo, con la implicación de "equilibrio de fuerzas"

Answer (score 2):

"No jala" (un aparato o máquina) significa "no funciona"
"jalar" (usado como verbo) se usa por "trabajar"
"jale" (sustantivo) "trabajo" o "negocio"
"jalador" (adjetivo) "que si coopera" "que si participa"
"jaladora" (adjetivo) Suele aplicarse a una mujer que le gusta ir a fiestas o a una mujer que tiene sexo con cualquiera.
"jalársela" por "masturbarse"
"no te la jales" por "no exageres"